# Eclipse: What are convenient or possible ways to search the JDK sources for a specific text?

Tags: java, eclipse

For example right now I would like to know which Look & Feel sets the UIManager property 'Button.defaultButtonFollowsFocus', and where.

The 'Java Search' dialog requires a 'Search For' option, which does not fit my text/string search.

The 'File Search' does not offer an option to search the JRE libraries.

[image: Java Search]

Comment: You might want to unpack the sources and just grep for this

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes thank you. Indeed I will, if there is no convenient way to do this via Eclipse. I've had this requirement many times before but just now realized how this should really be a core feature of any Java IDE.

Comment: The JDK sources are also [on GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/), which has a search feature.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Great tip, thank you!

Comment: @RetoHöhener The IntelliJ folks might implement it (if they haven't already) if you ask nicely.

Comment: If you unpack the sources to a directory under your project, the file search will probably do it.